# Wait for specific response in XHR polling with Cypress

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I have a cypress spec with which I want to test a function on my site which polls a third party API until it receives a correct answer and then shows more information for the user to continue with the function.

I start my spec with

```js
cy.server();
cy.route('GET', '**/that-other-api/**').as('otherApi');
```

I know that this part works. The route is listed in the top of the Cypress test GUI, and my `otherApi` alias is attached to the XHR requests when they are listed in the command list when running.

When the user (or my test) clicks a button the site will start polling that endpoint. When I receive a `status: success` in the response, the user (or my test) is provided with a filled dropdown of options and can continue.

How can I get Cypress to wait until I get that specific response from the XHR request (or reaches a cypress timeout) and then continue onwards?

The [Network request documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html) doesn't explain if this is possible or not. I have tried

```js
cy.wait('@billectaAccounts').should('have.property', 'response.body.status', 'success');
```

and just to see if stuff works

```js
cy.wait('@billectaAccounts').should('have.property', 'status', 201);
```

which both throw an error:

> InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').

Logging the response with

```js
cy.wait('@billectaAccounts').then(console.log);
```

logs the response and shows that my status variable is there, but is `pending` since it's only on the first request.

```
{
  "xhr": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://myapi/longToken",
    "id": "xhr193"
  },
  "id": "xhr193",
  "url": "https://myapi/longToken",
  "method": "GET",
  "status": 200,
  "statusMessage": "200 (OK)",
  "request": {
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "body": null
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate",
      "connection": "close",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Tue, 24 Mar 2020 08:32:09 GMT",
      "etag": "W/\"f0d6999f3be78c3dc8eab419745ec489\"",
      "referrer-policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
      "server": "Cowboy",
      "vary": "Origin",
      "via": "1.1 vegur",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-download-options": "noopen",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies": "none",
      "x-request-id": "id",
      "x-runtime": "0.006788",
      "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
    },
    "body": {
      "id": 721,
      "public_id": "longTokenId",
      "bank": "bank-id",
      "ssn": "ssn-number",
      "status": "pending",
      "created_at": "2020-03-24T09:32:05.362+01:00",
      "updated_at": "2020-03-24T09:32:06.028+01:00",
      "account_numbers": [],
      "token": "pollingToken"
    }
  },
  "duration": 230
}
```

I would prefer to not stub the response, It's nice to have the end to end test to that API.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the output of the console.log?

Comment: @mvoase Log output added!

Comment: Looks like this is not possible with Cypress yet: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7729. This ticket is specific to status code, but the suggested solution would be to make a callback containing a condition and then retry until the callback/condition returns true.